# Moving lines in opposite direction?

Tags: qgis, point, line

I have a street map where one street(consisting of 2 lanes each) is shown as one line. If I click on that line, there are two objects (one object for each lane) listed like in the following image:

[image]

For each object, I do have the From/To Node which gives me the direction of the lane. What I want to do is to assign street signs (which are represented as blue points) to the nearest lane. That is why I need to move both Lane objects in the opposite direction so they approach the proper street sign. In the end, it should look like this.

[image]

So, with respect to the direction of the vector, the vector must always be shifted to the right.

Is there some sort of algorithm to achieve this?

As I have to do this which 6000 other streets, I will probably have to write a python script to do this.

Is there a possibility to move curved lines too without converting them to points?

What I have tried so far is a QGIS plugin called "Line Offset" which creates a parallel line of a selected polyline feature at a given distance. I do not know if this plugin solves my problem, but I would like to give it a try. I unchecked all layers in my layer window except the street map layer. Furthermore, I selected (in the attribute table) all objects I want to move. In the plugin's interface, I have the following options set:

[image]

But it always stops running and gives me the following error:

[image]

Maybe someone has already worked with this plugin and can figure out what I am doing wrong. It says "QgsRasterLayer" object has no attribute.. but isn't my streetmap layer a polyline-layer?

This doesn't make sense to me.

---

I have selected both the layer and the objects of the layer, but I still get the same error.

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure your vector layer is selected (i.e. highlighted in the Layers Panel) before you ran the plugin?

Comment: @Joseph, I have indeed selected the layer and the layer objects (on which the plugin should do its work on). But I am still getting the error unfortunately.

Comment: Try removing the raster layers from the project. Re-highlighting the layer in the layers panel and trying again.

Comment: @applebrown - Before using the Line Offset plugin, you need to make sure your line layer is at the **bottom** of the layers panel _and_ you need to **select** the lines in your line layer. Also ensure you are using a projected CRS with metres as units.

Comment: @Joseph: I have reprojected the graph layer to EPSG:31255 which is a reprojected layer. The reprojected layer is at the bottom of the layers panel and I have selected all lines (they are yellow now). But when I run the lineOffset plugin, I get no output. It will also show me an error/warning note at the top of my qgis panel which tells me that the CRS was undefined - set to WGS84!! How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you confirm there was no output? That warning usually comes when the output is loaded (directly above your line layer in the _Layers Panel_). If there was an output, you could _right-click_ the layer and use the `Save As...` option to save it in the same CRS as your line layer. If no output was created then I'm unsure why that would be (the plugin has last been updated in April 2014 so it could a problem that it is not compatible with the latest version of QGIS although I tested this on 2.18.14 and it works as described).

Comment: For some reason `Line Offsest` plugin did not work for me in QGIS 2.18.16. Alternatively I used `Single sided buffers (and offset lines) for lines` tool, which is in the `Processing toolbox | GDAL/OGR | [OGR] Geoprocessing`. Hope this works for you too. (Just choose `Offset curve` option for the "Operation" option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been thinking about a similar project involving assigning street signs to a road network, primarily for stop sign and speed limit purposes, but my data is a bit different than yours.  I am mostly spit balling here, but I hope it will at least get you somewhere until someone can get you a better answer.

If you are aiming to identify which signs go on which roads. I would suggest using a buffer and a spatial select and avoid shifting lanes all together.  I would break all lines (if not already) at each intersection, so you have good topology.  That way each road segment goes from intersection to intersection.  I would then assign each segment a unique ID (you may already have this, if please disregard).  Then buffer all your lines (with a mitered end instead of a rounded one to avoid issues at intersections) and use a union or spatial join to determine which polygon street segment each street sign falls into.  I would also recommend performing a spatial join on the street signs to road signs to get a distance measurement for distance from all signs to roads to get an idea of what is a reasonable buffer zone.

Now is where it gets dicey, you will now have each sign assigned to each “piece” of road but you won’t necessarily know which lane it is in.  In order to identify which lane segment it is a part of, I would propose using python to parse through your list of street segments.  For each segment, I would grab the corresponding signs using a relate from the sign buffer by ID.  Then I would take the start and stop point of the road, or treat it as a vector your choice, and compare it to the lat longs of the street signs.  Using algebra/math you should be able to identify if the coordinates are on the right side of the vector, and assign that sign to the stream segment, or if it is on the left side in which you would ignore it since it’s on the wrong side of the road.  A quick search returned this https://community.esri.com/thread/45581

Alternatively I believe ArcMap has a buffer one side section that should get you most of the way there, but I believe it require an advanced license.